# Removing duplicates from a list and sorting it using python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am currently learning python and encourter problems while doing exercise provided from teacher. so i have a txt file contains a name list like the following

```
Noah

Liam

Madison

Jayden

Elizabeth

Jacob

Mia

Noah

Angelia

Bob

Cindy
```

and I am supposed to remove duplicates from the list, eg there are 2 'Noah' in the list and I am supposed to remove one of them and return a list that is alphabetically sorted such as

```
Angelia

Bob

Cindy
```

....

I have searched the internet and know about method where we apply set.
however my teacher specify in the comment and says

```
 for n in open('class_list.txt'):
# TODO: do something with n.strip() "
```

and I don't understand why use strip function here? isn't strip function just simply remove the 2 same string from the list if I write n.strip('Noah')? or do I interpret and use strip wrongly?

Comment: The strip function simply removes any leading/trailing whitespace (including spaces and tabs) and newline characters. Thus, it is how you get the raw string. You will need more logic than simply using `strip` to accomplish your task

Comment: Do you know how to read data from a TXT file in python? There is a reason for using `strip()`. Hint: see section 7.2.1 https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt your teacher meant to use strip() to eliminate duplicates, but to remove the whitespace after the name. 
Since this looks like a homework problem, i won't give you the solution, but i'll try to point you in the right direction.

You should probably know how to read data, either with `file = open("file")` or `with open("file") as f`. So, with a list of names, we can get around to eliminating duplicates. However, the word may include some nasty characters at the end of each word(`\n` in particular for a newline). In order to get around this, call `word.strip()` which destroys the unnecessary characters and whitespace at the end. So, when you reach a list of words, execute something like

```
for i in names:
    i = i.strip()
```

You are aware as you said of using sets, however, sets are unordered data types, so when you convert a list to a set(with `set(list)` and `list(set)`), and then the set back to a list, the order is lost. However, it is easily restored by a handy python function `sorted(list)`, that will alphabetically sort the names for you.

It is then trivial to print the list, with something to the effect of

```
for i in names: #names is your list 
    print(i)
```

**EDIT: If you aren't familiar with sets, there are more understandable ways, 
for example (this isn't very efficient):**

---

1. Keep an empty list of names to store names you have already seen (`seen`)
2. Iterate through your list of names, and for each name

   1. If the name is in `seen`, `list.pop(name)` it from your list of names.
   2. If it is not, add it to `seen` with `seen.append`
3. Print the list!

Comment: I upvoted this answer because you answered OPs question without doing his homework for him.

Comment: Thank you very much for the concept! it helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you interpreted `str.strip()` wrongly. What it does is it removes all white space at the beginning and at the end of the line. What you want to do is something like this

```
names = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line not in names:
            names.append(line.strip())
for name in names.sort():
    print name
```

What this does is it opens a file with names. Then you iterate over each line, each line is a name. You check whether that name has been already seen, if not, then add it to the `names`. At the end sort the unique names and print them.

Answer (score 1):

Add names to a `set` and sort it.

```
names = set()
with open('class_list.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            names.add(line.strip())

print('\n'.join(sorted(names)))
```

- Handles duplicates during insertion
- No additional `in` comparisons required

The use of `str.strip` is to eliminate trailing newlines when lines are read in from the file.

Comment: This doesn't deal with duplicates

Comment: @PokestarFan Do you know that a set can't contain duplicates?

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks

Comment: @campovski I am here, although I'm not _from_ here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ damn, they brainwash ppl really bad then... Hope you got the joke

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remove duplicates is to use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). This a a collection of elements without duplicates.

For instance, you can store the names like this:

```
names = set([])
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        names.add(line.strip())  # drop the trailing \n
```

Then, to sort the list:

```
names = sorted(names)
```

Python language has the concept of [comprehension list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (and set).

So, you can simplify the code like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    names = set(line.strip() for line in f)
names = sorted(names)
```

If your names are not only English names and contains non-ASCII characters, you may need to sort with you [locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html). One solution is as follow:

```
import locale

# this reads the environment and inits the right locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")

names = sorted(names, key=locale.strxfrm)
```

Comment: Fixed: `names = sorted(names)`